# iOS app validation problems: non-public API usage, libsqlite usage

Tags: ios, xcode, validation, sqlite

Once I tried to validate my iOS application on the appstore, I got the following error on XCODE:

> Your app contains non-public API usage. Please review the errors, correct them and resubmit your application.

The error doesn't provide an explanation on which are the non-public classes that we used. How can I get it?

> The app references non-public symbols in Payload/...app/libsqlite3.0.dylib: _dispatch_sources_type_vm, guarded_close_np, guarded_open_np

I have tried to solve the problem by removing `libsqlite3.dylib` from xcode and by adding linker flag '`-lsqlite3`' or '`-libsqlite3`' (with the last flag the app did not compiled).

How can I solve it?

Comment: In your codes, are there any warnings? If there are, check them. Maybe one of them causes the problem. It happened me once...

Comment: maybe this could help http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3546046/check-for-private-api-usage-yourself

Comment: I am not sure, where you are added the linker flag is not right place. Because it resolves the problem. Check it once..

Answer (score 0):

You could also just download the sqlite amalgamation and include the sqlite source code into your app. That would not link to the system libsqlite3.0.dylib and the problem would be avoided. Your app binary would get a little bit bigger, but the build/validation problems would go away.